# IIS 8.5 configuring CORS headers in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cors, iis-8

I have IIS v8.5 and I want to configure supporting CORS Headers.
I've added next settings in my web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

In case I make request to my controller it works fine, but I have java script in my folder, and when I make request to get this file I get response without header
"access-control-allow-origin". I want to serve static file with that header.
Is this possible?
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

It should work for static files as well. May be some code on server side is removing this header. As another option, you can use outbound rules, to set headers. Add this into your web.config (inside `rewrite` section):

```
<outboundRules>       
     <rule name="Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin" pattern="*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="*" />
    </rule>        
</outboundRules>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to fix it. Just added web.config with configs in folder with that script and it works.